# IBM MessageSight can not support Tomcat 8.5 or above for OAuth

Tags: tomcat, oauth, mqtt

Trying OAuth on IBM MessageSight with Tomcat8.0 and Tomcat8.5. The result is OK with Tomcat8.0, but failed with Tomcat8.5.

I did a sniffer to catch the message between IBM MessageSight and Tomcat server to check the difference. Also, checked the HTTP Responses' difference between Tomcat8.0 and Tomcat8.5.

Findings were:

1. Tomcat8.5 skips to return Reason-Phrase of HTTP response's Status. For example:

   Tomcat8.0 HTTP Response status > HTTP/1.1 200 OK

   Tomcat8.5 HTTP Response status > HTTP/1.1 200

   (a related bug report "missing reason phrase in tomcat 8.5.x" as the link - https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60183)
2. IBM MessageSight can not handle this change, then causes OAuth falied.

Although, there is a workaround to overcome the change of Tomcat8.5. However, I still need to please IBM MessageSight to comply with the change. Otherwise, my client will skip the solution with IBM MessageSight.

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking here, I can't see an actual question. I suspect you should really open this as a bug under your MessageSight support contract but you will have to provide a lot more information about exactly what you did and the expected outcome

Answer (score 0):

1. As of Tomcat 8.5, the HTTP reason phrase is not written anymore, since it's not required and should not be read by HTTP clients: See this Spring Boot issue for more details.
2. From [tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/changelog.html](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/changelog.html): RFC 7230 states that clients should ignore reason phrases in HTTP/1.1 response messages. Since the reason phrase is optional, Tomcat no longer sends it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following attribute to your `Connection` in `conf\server.xml`:

```
sendReasonPhrase="true"
```

In Tomcat 8.5.x the reason phrase was no longer sent by default, but this enables it again.